# Looking for a movie/show title where some people have their mind transferred into other bodies

Tags: story-identification, tv

I'm looking for a movie or maybe a show where for some reason, people's minds can be transferred into another body.
I don't have a lot of memories of why/how the transfer occurs. It can be some kind magic, maybe to get dead people back in a random body ...

I only remember a specific scene where the main character walks into a building and he sees a couple crying because they get their young girl back but the kid is in a old woman's body (like 80 years old with long grey hair). The kid is crying because she doesn't understand why she's in an old body. This scene lasts maybe 10 seconds.

The movie/show is not very old (2010+ I think) probably from USA.

Comment: Sounds like a scene from the TV version of Altered Carbon.

Comment: Yes it's this thank you, I just find the exact scene "Ortega meets Kovacs for the first time | Altered Carbon" on youtube

Comment: You could try Pixar's Soul

Comment: Sounds like [Les dissociés](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5lUBlW72qBQ)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds like a scene from the TV version of [Altered Carbon](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2261227/) in which [Ortega meets Kovacs for the first time](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=KSksOxzwSmY).

Comment: This is close to a link-only answer which, if it were not the accepted one, would be subject to deletion.  You can improve this answer by including some additional detail (besides the links) supporting this as the correct answer.